# How to delay PHP email using sleep

Tags: php, email, delay

I'm using a php script to send an email that I want to send after a time delay. I am going to use `sleep()` for that. But where would I put that to delay the email from sending? Here's my code:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

 $headers = "From: Memory Jet <your_company@example.com>\r\n";


$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];
//I originally put the delay here, it didn't work
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);

} ?>
```

Thanks in advance! =) -Ben

Comment: put it before the `mail()` function and it will sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two questions: 1) What do you mean by "it didn't work"; what did it do? 2) Why do you want to wait a long time before sending the email?

Also, I would highly recommend against calling `sleep()` in your PHP scripts, as it will delay completion of the script, and thus, the HTML to the browser.

I would implement a more robust Email queuing system. Basically, instead of sending the email in the script, you insert a row into a database, which contains a queue of emails to be sent. Then, you have a `cron` or other background process, that periodically checks the database for emails to be sent, and then sends them in a batch.

Additionally, you could specify a "to-be-sent time" in the table, and the sender script would not send any emails until the current time is after that "to-be-sent time".

The problem with sleep()ing is that the PHP script fires up, executes, then is gone. In order to do something in the (relatively) distant future, you need *something* else. `cron` was just an example. You could use something in windows task scheduler (you didn't mention target platform), or write your own program. It wouldn't be a whole lot of work to write something in C (or maybe even PHP) that runs continually, checking the database and sending emails).

Comment: The script didn't load. I'll have to try it again I thought it was an error

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?301942-Insert-time-delay-into-mail-sending

Comment: @DevinGund, ah, to mimic a real person's delay. That makes sense :-)

Comment: Is there another way to have an email sent out in an x amount of time? Cron is not what I would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a php script to send an email that I want to send after a time delay. I am going to use sleep() for that.

Don't. If you do this in a user-triggered script, it will delay the final page rendering for the user until the sleep call is finished. It'll also tie up an Apache server worker for the entire time. If you've got heavy load and a 10 second delay you could wind up DOSing yourself off the Internet. Also, if the user closes the page before the end of the delay, the e-mail will never be sent.

Use cron or a daemon to do this.

Comment: NOT TRUE! The script continues running after a user has closed the page!